# Reduce array of numbers (sequence)

Tags: ruby, arrays, range, sequence

Imagine having an array of numbers defined as: `a = [18, 20, 21, 22, 23]`. I want to modify it so that it would look like this: `a = [18, (20..23)]`. What is the most elegant solution for that one?

Comment: The next question could be: produce full array from reduced one. )

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev that's easier: `a.flat_map{|e| [*e]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code minimally modified from [doc: Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before).

```
i = a[0]
a.slice_before do |e|
  i, j = e, i
  j + 1 != e
end
.flat_map{|es| es.length < 3 ? es : es.first..es.last}
# => [18, 20..23]
```

Comment: why `es.length < 3`? not `es.length < 2`

Comment: I've rewritten it myself, so no worries :)

Comment: @Dmitri What have you rewritten? Any worries? By the way, I fixed a problem that I noticed.

Comment: @sawa es.length < 3 changed that one to es.length < 2. Just as it is in the link you gave (slice_before)

Comment: @Dmitri Why did you change it? In the link I gave, it is `<= 2`, which is the same as `< 3`.

Comment: Do you have any reason you changed it?

Comment: @sawa I don't know if it is me, but with < 3 it doesn't work. with < 2 it does.

Comment: @Dmitri If that is what you want, it is fine, but I think the purpose of using `-` is to shorten the description. Instead of writing `1, 2, 3`, it shortens things to write `1-3` by omitting the intermediate numbers. But I don't think rewriting `1, 2` to `1-2` will shorten anything, and it just adds a level of complication for introducing `-` for nothing. And usually, people do not do that.

Comment: In your case, converting `1, 2` into `1..2` would not shorten anything.

Comment: @sawa OK :) Thank you so much. 

I had another question as well, related to this topic. What if this initial array contains subsequence already ?
a = [18, (20..22), 23] 
It throws an error: Undefined method '+' for Range.
And also, sometimes it produces two or more subsequences which are parts of large sequence, e.g 
# => [(1..2), (3..4)]. 
Can this be optimized somehow, so that it would produce (1..4) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [18, 20, 21, 22, 23,13,14].sort!
prev = a[0]
p a.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.flat_map{|i| next Range.new(i.first,i.last) if i.size !=1 ; i}
#=> [13..14, 18, 20..23]
```